# I can'yt boot Windows XP after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows-xp

I can't boot Windows XP after installing Ubuntu 12.04
and what is worst is that I don't have the Windows XP installation CD.

```
kathy@kathy-HP-Compaq:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for kathy: 

Disk /dev/sda: 80.0 GB, 80026361856 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9729 cylinders, total 156301488 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc51bc51b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63    41957999    20978968+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        41958061   156301311    57171625+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        41958063   101887679    29964808+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       154224640   156301311     1038336   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       101888000   154222591    26167296   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 1063 MB, 1063256064 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 129 cylinders, total 2076672 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x693811c2

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

please teach me how to do this things cuz i got limited knowledge in computer teach me like u teach your little sister.

Comment: Please provide more details. Now, your post is too general so no one can help you.

Comment: And in the process your caps-lock seems to got stuck...

Comment: Could you please add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` (to your question) and/or a screenshot of [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/) (use http://imgur.com)

Answer (score 0):

Just install boot-repair and try to restore mbr.
Type this in terminal (CTRL + Alt+T)

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`

or use live ubuntu cd/usb and install equivalent MBR to your sda drive by doing the following (it helps you to boot directly into Windows again if all goes well):

1. `sudo apt-get install lilo`
2. `sudo lilo -M  /dev/sda mbr`

Comment: oooh my its getting mess up, more complicated! can u plz instruct me how to get rid of ubuntu and bring back all my old system back? its giving me headache. huhuhu!!!...., plz do help!

Comment: Do you have windows xp cd or ubuntu cd/usb?

Comment: i dont have windows xp cd but i do have ubuntu usb..... plzzzzz help!

Comment: when i done -----
    sudo apt-get install lilo,
    sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr--
after restart it shows menu on how windows xp to open i choose to open like open last good configuration, and few of the menu but all i see is the windows xp screen loading but after stop and back to menu again and again....

Comment: Did you try installing boot-repair from ubuntu live usb?

    `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`
    `sudo apt-get update`
    `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`

I suppose  that windows xp boot loader is corrupted and if commands above doesn't fix it. Probably you'll need the windows xp cd to recover windows xp boot loader.